# I'm trying to Import sheets from Excel to Access. It imports data it but does not return the exact content of the spreadsheet. Office 2019

Tags: ms-access, excel-2010

The code line I'm using is:-
`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, ShtName, Path, True, "A1:J10"` 
The top 2 rows of data in the spreadsheet reads:-

```
ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9
 1 |  A |  B |  C |  D |  E |  F |  G |  H |  I
```

with the top 2 rows of spread data imported into the Database returns as:-

```
 C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9 | F10
  A |  B |  C |  D |  E |  F |  G |  H |  I
```

NOTE:- if I do the import manually the whole table imports perfectly. I have a large number of sheets/tables to import so this is not really an option.

I am using Office 2019.

My guess is that it has something to do with different data types, but I have no idea on how to approach the problem and any help would be wonderful.

I have tried changing the format of the "ID" column in the spreadsheet to a text column but to no avail. I have no idea at all where the "F10" column header in the database is coming from.

Comment: So the table `ShtName` doesn't exist yet, when you run this? In that case I assume there is some guessing involved on Access side, which apparently goes wrong. -- Is importing into existing table(s) an option?

Comment: Usual workflow is: Link (not import) the spreadsheet, then import from linked table into existing table. Then remove link.

Comment: That's odd behavior. Does `shtName` exist prior to running this? Do you see similar strange shifting behavior when you run this with any other range? "B1:K10" or "A1:E5"?

Comment: Could post in a discussion forum that allows attaching files and provide workbook for analysis.

Comment: The Dim's code I'm using is:-                                                            Sub Import_H2V()
    Dim Shts As Integer
    Dim ShtName As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim SNum As Integer
    Dim WkBk As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim TblName As String

Comment: JNevill Very good question. Well I tried it and for the "B1:K10" version the top two lines retun as:-
 C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 | C8 | C9 | F9 | C1
   B |  C   |   D |  E  |   F |  G  |  H  |  I  |      |  I 
That is all quite logical if one accepts the identified errors (Note:- C1 is the start of the next block of data).
The "A1:E5" version returns exactly as one would expect it to ie. correctly.

Comment: Well thank you all. I've found a flaw in my logic and I should now do able to get correct data imported!